# How Can I insert multiple image in WYSIWYG Editor in Magento1.9.x?

Tags: magento-1.9, image-upload, wysiwyg, multiple-file-upload

Magento1.9.x version in need multiple image upload at a time in WYSIWYG Editor.

[image]